# named running as root cannot read named.conf

Tags: linux, bind, file-permissions

Tried running named as my own user on an Ubuntu box, and it couldn't read the named.conf file:

```
named -d 9 -c named.conf -g
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 starting BIND 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.4-Ubuntu -d 9 -c named.conf -g
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--with-atf=no' '--enable-ipv6' '--enable-rrl' '--enable-filter-aaaa' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2'
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 ----------------------------------------------------
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 BIND 9 is maintained by Internet Systems Consortium,
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 Inc. (ISC), a non-profit 501(c)(3) public-benefit 
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 corporation.  Support and training for BIND 9 are 
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 available at https://www.isc.org/support
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 ----------------------------------------------------
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 found 8 CPUs, using 8 worker threads
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.698 using 8 UDP listeners per interface
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.699 using up to 4096 sockets
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.699 Registering DLZ_dlopen driver
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.699 Registering SDLZ driver 'dlopen'
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.699 Registering DLZ driver 'dlopen'
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.700 decrement_reference: delete from rbt: 0x7fbd40eb6068 .
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.703 loading configuration from '/tmp/name/named.conf'
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.703 open: /tmp/name/named.conf: permission denied
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.703 load_configuration: permission denied
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.703 loading configuration: permission denied
19-Aug-2015 11:33:10.703 exiting (due to fatal error)
```

I opened up the permissions on named.conf:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 don  don    4096 Aug 19 11:31 ./
drwxrwxrwt 26 root root 118784 Aug 19 11:35 ../
-rwxrwxrwx  1 don  don     387 Aug 19 11:33 named.conf*
```

I tried running as root with the same result:

```
sudo named -d 9 -c named.conf -g
```

The OS is ubuntu:

```
uname -a
Linux don-asus 3.16.0-46-generic #62~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 11 16:27:16 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This all works fine on OSX and another Ubuntu box. What else on Linux can block access to open a file?

Edit:

```
>sudo apparmor_status
apparmor module is loaded.
24 profiles are loaded.
24 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
...
```

So - it looks like it *is* active.

Comment: Is SELinux or AppArmor active?

Comment: Nope, neither one.

Comment: That is to say, AppArmor is installed, but there are no apparmor processes running.

Comment: If apparmor is installed, can you add `sudo apparmor_status` output to the question?

Comment: Okay, added a partial output. Looks like it is active.

Comment: Can I disable it without uninstalling?

Comment: Added the file to the AppArmor config, recompiled, and now it works. Thank you. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As was found based on the discussion in the comments, AppArmor was found to be loaded (based on `sudo apparmor_status` output).

When AppArmor is loaded and has rules in enforce mode it can do things like deny specific processes from accessing anything but specific paths.

I wouid assume what is happening here is that it has rules for BIND which ensures that the `named` process can only access something like `/etc/bind`, `/var/cache/bind`, `/var/lib/bind` (the paths that the default Debian/Ubuntu BIND configuration uses).

If you want to completely disable the profile, [Ubuntu's Help Wiki AppArmor page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) details how to disable a profile:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/profile.name /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/profile.name
```

Alternatively you can adjust the rules for the BIND profile and reload it:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/profile.name
```